# Sizing pattern element based on viewport

Tags: svg, background, background-image

I have a large svg image that will be scrolled. I would like to add a tiled background image behind all the elements. This is currently leaving me with two problems:

1. I haven't found a way to keep a background image fixed, and not scroll it with the svg elements on top of it.
2. Assuming that's not possible, I wanted to size the tile elements to occupy 20% of the viewable area rather than 20% of the total svg size.

```html
<svg width="3560.00px" height="1350.00px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
    <pattern id="G-BG" width="20.00%" height="20.00%">
        <image xlink:href="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/000/301/800/small/jfyo_waxi_190121.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="20.00%" height="20.00%"/>
    </pattern>
</defs>

<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#G-BG)" fill-opacity="0.20"/>

<circle fill="green" cx="200" cy="200" r="100.00"/>
</svg>
```

If you run this little example, it sets a background composed of 5 x 5 copies of some arbitrary image, but the repeat interval of the tiling is based on 20% of the full svg size. If I try and use vw/vh units then the pattern size seems to go to zero, and so disappear.

My ideal choice would be to have a fixed 5 x 5 image that doesn't scroll, but the CSS background support doesn't seem to work for for svg.

My second choice would be to have a scrolling background image, but where there are 5 x 5 tiles visible at any one time.

Can either of these goals be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is anything here that might help?

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper svg{
    background-color: 'red';
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
    <pattern id="pattern" width="0.2" height="0.25" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
      <image width="0.5" height="0.5"  href="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/000/301/800/small/jfyo_waxi_190121.jpg" />
    </pattern>
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern)"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really @James. It's lost the wide svg content (which seems to be the primary cause), and it's now using inline svg.

Comment: If I had the option of using HTML around the SVG (which I don't) then I could easily fix this with a full-sized div making use of all the great CSS background-* settings. As the question says, though, they don't appear to work with SVG elements.

Comment: Completely understand. Good luck, I'm sure someone will work it out.